# How to transfer user data from production to preproduction?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

We have a payroll system where users input their worked hours. There is a database of users with names, emails, addresses, input hours etc. We want to transfer that data to preprod for testing purposes.

My question is: How should we go about transferring personal data in compliance with GDPR? Should we absolutely replace the user data or there are other ways?

Comment: I write here because I don't have a complete answer. From my experience: if the preproduction environment is accessed by the same people of production and nobody else can access data: in this case you are safe. Otherwise you can delete or anonymize database. I prefer anonymize, so you have a near real data distribution. You can search tools to anonymize database. Sadly I don't have experience on them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the data in a preprod env has to be absolutely equal to the data in prod, if that isnt the case you can use a library to fill your preprod database a library like [faker](https://fakerjs.dev/) can do the job.

Concerning GDPR, if the both database are hosted by the same service, same server same timezone, you are not breaking in rules but if a user that requests his data to be removed, it has to be removed in Production and Preprod env.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Personal data like name, email, etc can be changed. What we care about is the input worked hours. Would you say there are any pros of faker over let's say replacing name with initials? (to make sure the user on prod is the same as on preprod)

Comment: @ErmekBarmashev if the data doesnt have to be equal to prod, just use a faker library there is a bunch out there i'm jusre you will find that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A pre-production environment should by definition be as near as humanly possible to the production environment. As long as you have the same privacy protections in that environment as in the production environment (restrictions to need-to-know, ability to extract data at request, ability to purge data at request, and so on), I don't see why GDPR should be a hindrance. You need to have measures in place to ensure the data-in-motion part doesn't fall into the wrong hands, of course: sometimes, encryption actually **is** the answer to security issues!

IANAL, of course: there sometimes seem to be about as many interpretations of GDPR as there are citizens in the EU…